# Eclipse don't display javadoc for javax

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket, javadoc

I can't find out how to make Eclipse (EE Oxygen Release (4.7.0) Build id: 20170620-1800) display javadocs for my Java EE libs (javax.websocket). I get "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found." information.
It works fine for Java SE libs.

Any ideas?
I could add javadoc manually, but I have no idea which one lib it is in eclipse.I have: Apache Tomcat v9.0, EAR Libraries, JRE System Library[jre1.8.0_131], Web App Libraries

Comment: Did you bother to do a web search for, say, _"eclipse display javadoc for javaee classes"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had to go to project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Apache Tomcat ... -> find websocket-api.jar -> attach javadoc here

Found on google info to link it to servlet-api.jar, but it didn't work, so I tried to different jar, and it worked out.